How can I call the rest api "BindToGateway" from c#?
I am working through trying to programmatically bind a Semantic Model to a gateway.  I have found the below rest api that makes it look possible but I am running into a problem that I can't seem to get around just yet.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/bind-to-gateway-in-group#code-try-0
Below is the code I am attempting to use and I expect it to complete successfully and bind the gateway.
 public static void BindGatewaytoDataset(string groupId, string datasetId, string bearer)
 {

   
     var client = new RestClient($"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.BindToGateway");
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

     request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);

     var gatewayObjectID =  new Guid("GATEWAYOBJECTID");
     var datasourceObjectIds = new Guid("DATASOURCE");

     request.AddJsonBody(new
     {
         gatewayObjectId = gatewayObjectID,
         datasourceObjectIds = datasourceObjectIds
         
     });



     IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

     if (response.IsSuccessful)
     {
         // The request was successful
         Console.WriteLine("Gateway assigned to dataset successfully.");
     }
     else
     {
         // The request failed
         Console.WriteLine($"Failed to assign gateway to dataset: {response.StatusCode}");
     }
 }

The error I'm getting seems to be with the datasourceObjectIds  and the api wanting that to be a list.  below is that error.
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Bad Request","details":[{"message":"Error converting value \"DATASOURCEGUID\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Guid]'. Path 'datasourceObjectIds', line 1, position 118.","target":"bindToGatewayRequest.datasourceObjectIds"}]}}


As soon as I asked this I found the answer so I'm posting it here in case someone else gets stuck like i was.
change the var datasource id to this:
var datasourceObjectIds = new List { new Guid("DATASOURCE GUID") };
